# Compiling Boost.Python toy example fails: ''error: expected unqualified-id before ‘%’ token %%bp_module"

Tags: boost-python

I'm trying to compile a toy example using Boost.Python. I can compile the "quickstart" example.

However when I try to compile this toy example smoke_test.cpp:

```
%%bp_module smoke_test
#include <boost/python.hpp>
int test() {return 42; }
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(smoke_test)
{
  boost::python::def("test",test);
}
```

and smoke_test.py:

```
import smoke_test
smoke_test.test()
```

using this Jamfile:

```
import python ;
import testing ;

project quickstart
  : requirements
    <location>.
    ;

# Declare a Python extension called hello.
python-extension extending : smoke_test.cpp ;
```

I get the following error:

```
smoke_test.cpp:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘%’ token
 %%bp_module smoke_test
 ^
```

Does anyone know whats going wrong? I assume my Jamfile is incorrect but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I'm using boos 1.63.0 and python 2.7.

Comment: What's the first line: `%%bp_module smoke_test` doing there? That's garbage. Remove it and try to compile again.

Comment: It's from the tutorial I read. I now removed the line. It now compiles but upon running `python smoke_test.py 
 I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test'

Comment: I'd try removing `import testing ;` from the jam file. Anyway I'm not familiar with boost jam, if you can do without it then you can build working module by: `g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include smoke_test.cpp -shared -lpython2.7 -lboost_python-py27 -o smoke_test.so`

Comment: Yeah the Jamfile is extremely confusing. It was part of the official boost documentation though - which seems quite sh**** anyway. Lukily I found a small Makefile. I will post the Makefile as an edit. Not sure what the `%%bp_module smoke_test` was supposed to do. I assume all these parts highly rely on the boost version that is used. For now I switched back to the Ubuntu 14.04 system version (1.48.0 if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `%%bp_module smoke_test` line was false as mentioned by @doqtor. This was probably a toy example made for ipython notebook only. Although I couldn't figure out how to use `bjam` and `Jamfile`s to compile the code, I'm still now able to compile with this [minimal Makefile example](https://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/configuring-boostpython-and-hello-boost/) using my Ubuntu 14.04 system boost version (1.54.0):

```
PYTHON_VERSION = 2.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE = /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)

# location of the Boost Python include files and library

BOOST_INC = /usr/include
BOOST_LIB = /usr/lib

# compile mesh classes
TARGET = smoke_test

$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
    g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python -L/usr/lib/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)/config -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION) -o $(TARGET).so

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).cpp
    g++ -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -fPIC -c $(TARGET).cpp
```